# Dealing with Function1 type parameters in trait

Tags: scala

I have a problem with having a Function1 in my trait and make things work correctly, let's say I have the following trait

```
trait Foo[+X, +O, Z<:X]{
  def bar: Z => O
  def args:Option[Z]
}

case class A1(args:Option[String] = None) extends Foo[String,String,String]{
    def bar = (x:String) => x+"..."
  }

  case class A2(args:Option[Int] = None) extends Foo[Int,String,Int]{
    def bar = (x:Int) => x.toString
  }

val mylist = List(A1(),A2())
```

The reason that I have type Z is for type signature of Function1 which is [T1-,R+]. I want `mylist` has type of `Foo[Any,Any,Any]` now it is `Foo[Any,Any,_ >: Int with String]`. So basically I want Z to be covariant too which is impossible. How should I define my trait to solve these problems?

Comment: What are you trying to use this for exactly? Is there something wrong with `Nothing` showing up? Would `Option[Any]` be acceptable?

Comment: @badcook it's a simplified version of what I want to do, but I want to have class containing the argument of the function and the function and bunch other meta data for that(number of inputs, output, ...)

Comment: In your example you are basically making `Z` invariant in a somewhat complicated way. You could define your trait just as `trait Foo[Z, +O]`. OR are you using `X` somewhere in a covariant position? Then you should add such usage to your example.

Comment: Z is invariant and that cannot change with that signatures

Comment: You said it yourself: what you want to do us impossible.  And it seems that you understand why. So, what is the question?

Comment: @SaschaKolberg if I define it as Z then my list will bot become List[Any...

Comment: @Dima yes, as you said I understand the problem, I;m looking for a solution or an alternative

Comment: @Omid well, you can't be possibly looking for a solution as you know it is impossible. That leaves the alternative. What is it that you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @Omid Why does it have to be `List[Any, Any]`? How about: `val mylist: List[_, _] = List(A1(),A2())`?